# UIColorPickerViewController works incorrect in iOS 17.1

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, ios17, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

There is no close button on the UIColorPickerViewController(can't exit color picker menu) right now. how can we solve on iOS 17.1

Also I found :https://www.reddit.com/r/MarvisApp/comments/1731zwo/cant_exit_color_picker_menu/?share_id=q49BYewvMTgX9GcLibIHA&utm_content=2&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_source=share&utm_term=1

```
  let vc = UIColorPickerViewController()
  vc.delegate = self
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
 if let selectedColor = selectedColor {
      vc.selectedColor = selectedColor
 }
 present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just changed this and solved :

```
 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
```